# Number of pairs with a given sum and product

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an array `A` along with 3 variables `k`, `x` and `y`. 
I have to find number of unordered pairs `(i,j)` such that the sum of two elements mod `k` equals `x` and the product of the same two elements mod `k` is equal to `y`. Pairs need not be distinct.  In other words, the number of `(i,j)` so that

`(A[i]+A[j])%k == x` and `(A[i]*A[j])%k == y` where `0 <= i < j < size of A`.

For example, let `A={1,2,3,2,1}`, `k=2`, `x=1`, `y=0`. Then the answer is 6, because the pairs are: `(1,2)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,3)`, `(2,1)`, `(3,2)`, and `(2,1)`.

I used a brute force approach, but obviously this is not acceptable.

Comment: What is wrong with the brute force approach? Could you provide some code for it?

Comment: I've cleaned up the formatting and grammar of your question.  But it's not clear if you want ordered or unordered pairs: is (1,2) the same as (2,1) or not?  Also, you say that `i` and `j` are the entries of the array, but `A[i]` would mean that `i` is an index.  Finally, could you explain what's wrong with the `O(n^2)` brute force approach?  Even showing us your brute force approach would be nice, since that would answer these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo-arithmetic has the following two rules:

```
((a mod k) * (b mod k)) mod k = (a * b) mod k
((a mod k) + (b mod k)) mod k = (a + b) mod k
```

Thus we can sort all values into a hashtable with [separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) and `k` buckets.

### Addition

Find `m < k`, such that for a given `n < k`: `(n + m) mod k = x`.
There is exactly one solution to this problem:

- if `n < x`: `m < x` must hold. Thus `m = x - n`
- if `n == x`: `m = 0`
- if `n > x`: we need to find `m` such that `n + m = x + k`. Thus `m = x + k - n`

This way, we can easily determine for each list of values the corresponding values such that for any pair `(a, b)` of the crossproduct of the two lists `(a + b) mod k = x` holds.

### Multiplication

Multiplication is a bit trickier. Luckily we've already been given the matching congruence-class for addition (see above), which must as well be the matching congruence-class for the multiplication, since both constraints need to hold. To verify that the given congruence-class matches, we only need to check that `(n * m) mod k = y` (`n` and `m` defined as above). If this expression holds, we can build pairs, otherwise no matching elements exist.

### Implementation

This would be the working python-code for the above example:

```
def modmuladd(ls, x, y, k):
    result = []

    # create tuples of indices and values
    indices = zip(ls, range(0, len(ls)))

    # split up into congruence classes
    congruence_cls = [[] for i in range(0, k)]
    for p in indices:
        congruence_cls[p[0] % k].append(p)

    for n in range(0, k):
        # congruence class to match addition
        if n < x:
            m = x - n
        elif n == x:
            m = 0
        else:
            m = x + k - n

        # check if congruence class matches for multiplication
        if (n * m) % k != y or len(congruence_cls[m]) == 0:
            continue    # no matching congruence class

        # add matching tuple to result
        result += [(a, b) for a in congruence_cls[n] for b in congruence_cls[m] if a[1] <= b[1]]
        result += [(a, b) for a in congruence_cls[m] for b in congruence_cls[n] if a[1] <= b[1]]

    # sort result such according to indices of first and second element, remove duplicates
    sorted_res = sorted(sorted(set(result), key=lambda p: p[1][1]), key=lambda p: p[0][1])

    # remove indices from result-set
    return [(p[0][0], p[1][0]) for p in sorted_res]
```

Note that sorting and elimination of duplicates is only required since this code concentrates on the usage of congruence-classes than perfect optimization. This example can be easily tweaked to provided ordering without the sorting by minor modifications.

### Test run

```
print(modmuladd([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 1, 0, 2))
```

Output:

> [(1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2), (2, 1)]

EDIT:

Worst-case complexity of this algorithm is still `O(n^2)`, due to the fact that building all possible pairs of a list of size `n` is `O(n^2)`. With this algorithm however the search for matching pairs can be cut down to `O(k)` with `O(n)` preprocessing. Thus counting resulting pairs can be done in `O(n)` with this approach. Assuming the numbers are distributed equally over the congruence-classes, this algorithm could build all pairs that are part of the solution-set in `O(n^2/k^2)`.

EDIT 2:
An implementation that only counts would work like this:

```
def modmuladdct(ls, x, y, k):
    result = 0

    # split up into congruence classes
    congruence_class = {}
    for v in ls:
        if v % k not in congruence_class:
            congruence_class[(v % k)] = [v]
        else:
            congruence_class[v % k].append(v)

    for n in congruence_class.keys():
        # congruence class to match addition
        m = (x - n + k) % k

        # check if congruence class matches for multiplication
        if (n * m % k != y) or len(congruence_class[m]) == 0:
            continue    # no matching congruence class

        # total number of pairs that will be built
        result += len(congruence_class[n]) * len(congruence_class[m])

    # divide by two since each pair would otherwise be counted twice
    return result // 2
```

Each pair would appear exactly twice in the result: once in-order and once with reversed order. By dividing the result by two this is being corrected. Runtime is `O(n + k)` (assuming dictionary-operations are `O(1)`).

Comment: Complexity falls down to O(n) right ?
Also can you explain n < x and m < x case?

Comment: @rohit1248 nope. The complexity for building the tuples is still worst-case `O(n^2)`. This approach only speeds up finding the matching equivalence-classes to `O(1)`. Building the actual pairs can't be done faster. Average-case would be `O(n^2/k^2)`, assuming the values are distributed equally over congruence-classes. The `n < x` case was actually "thus `m < x` must hold. Basically if `n < x` the two smallest `m` that satisfy the equation would be `m = x - n` and `m = x - n + k`. But the second one violates the constraint `m < k`, since `x - n > 0`.

Comment: @rohit1248 it is impossible to get below a worst-case of `O(n^2)` in this case, since actual pairs of input-values have to be built. Nevertheless this solution introduces a major improvement, since the **search** for pairs that would belong to the solution can be speed up to `O(k)` with `O(n)` preprocessing.

Comment: The question seems to suggest we need only the _number_ of pairs, not the pairs themselves. And the counting is O(n+k) if, for each remainder modulo k, we store how much values have this remainder.

Comment: @Gassa I've provided the approach for building pairs, since the question provided those as well. And the answer pointed out it's fairly simple to count pairs using the same approach without actually building pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The number of loops is C(2, n) = 5!/(2!(5-2)! = 10 loops in your case, and there is nothing magic that would drastically reduce the number of loops.
In JS you can do:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1];
k = 2;
x = 1;
y = 0;
for(i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
  for(j=i+1; j<A.length; j++) {
    if ((A[i]+A[j])%k !== x) {
        continue;
    }
    if ((A[i]*A[j])%k !== y) {
        continue;
    }
    console.log('('+A[i]+', '+A[j]+')');
  }
}
```

Comment: You could optimize the whole problem using modulo-arithmetic. While this doesn't speed up the building-time of the overall result, it definitely speeds up the search-time for matching pairs considerably.

Comment: This is unrelated to anything serious, but every reference I know of uses `C(n,2)`, not `C(2,n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring `A`, we can find all solutions of `n * (x - n) == y mod k` for 0 <= `n` < `k`. That's a simple O(`k`) algorithm -- check each such `n` in turn.

We can count, for each `n`, how often `A[i] == n`, and then reconstruct the counts of pairs. For if `cs` is an array of these counts, and `n` is a solution of `n * (x - n) == y mod k`, then there's `cs[n] * cs[(x-n)^k]` pairs of things in `A` that solve our equations corresponding to this `n`. To avoid double counting we only count `n` such that `n < (x - n) % k`.

```
def count_pairs(A, k, x, y):
    cs = [0] * k
    for a in A:
        cs[a % k] += 1
    pairs = ((i, (x-i)%k) for i in xrange(k) if i * (x-i) % k == y)
    return sum(cs[i] * cs[j] for i, j in pairs if i < j)

print count_pairs([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 2, 1, 0)
```

Overall, this constructs the counts in O(|`A`|) time, and the remaining code runs in O(`k`) time. It uses O(`k`) space.